# Oracle Get Records where String not present as Sub string in other rows?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, substring

Hi This is my problem:-

```
Value
-----
ABCDE
ABCD
ABC
ABF
ABFG
```

Result should be : ABCDE  & ABFG

above are not substrings of any other string with in the same column without recurs

Answer (score 4):

You can do:

```
select *
from my_table t1
where not exists (
  select 1 from my_table t2
  where t1.value <> t2.value 
    and t2.value like '%' || t1.value || '%'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with a LEFT JOIN combined with a WHERE .., IS NULL.

Compared to the correlated query solution, the LEFT JOIN query has a shorter/cleaner syntax, and often performs better when dealing with large datasets.

```
SELECT t1.value
FROM 
    my_table t1
    LEFT JOIN my_table t2 
        ON t2.value <> t1.value 
        AND t2.value LIKE '%' || t1.value || '%'
WHERE t2.value IS NULL
```